# "I got used to" or "I have got used to"

Tags: grammar, past-tense, present-tense, perfect-aspect

Here is the sentence
- Living in a foreign country isn’t strange to me now. I got used/ I have got used to living in a foreign country

Which one is correct and what the difference between them?

Comment: American English would be _gotten_.

Comment: This is used in exactly the same way as "I did that; I have done that". The only wrinkle is that *got* looks the same in both tenses (except in AmE, as @KarlG notes). See "I ate; I have eaten" in [our handy chart](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/21847/18696).

Comment: I've nominated a sample question. There are others in the sidebar on that question and on the chart question.